# How to add linking images to ckeditor in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, ckeditor5

I want to add **Linking images** feature to my React app that uses '

```
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document
```

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import * as  DecoupledEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document";
```

but when I import:

```
import linkimage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/linkimage';
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

more info about [images linking](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-linking.html#demo)

[image]

How can I add linking images?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have done:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-image
```

and enabled the plugin with:

```
import LinkImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/linkimage';
```

then add this into your editor config:

```
image: {
    toolbar: [
        'imageStyle:block',
        'imageStyle:side',
        '|',
        'toggleImageCaption',
        'imageTextAlternative',
        '|',
        'linkImage' <---- here
    ]
}
```

even if the error still persist, try the error code docs for it [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules)

```
Packages were duplicated in node_modules

In some situations, especially when calling npm install multiple times, it may happen that npm will not correctly "deduplicate" packages.

Normally, npm deduplicates all packages so, for example, @ckeditor/ckeditor5-core is installed only once in node_modules/. However, it is known to fail to do so from time to time.

We recommend checking if any of the steps listed below help:

    rm -rf node_modules && npm install to make sure you have a clean node_modules/ directory. This step is known to help in most cases.
    If you use yarn.lock or package-lock.json, remove it before npm install.
    Check whether all CKEditor 5 packages are up to date and reinstall them if you changed anything (rm -rf node_modules && npm install).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it make error :   Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules - Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Comment: I also had problems like this and yes the link you provided points to the problem which is usually with the `node_modules`, you can try this
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#:~:text=We%20recommend%20checking,npm%20install).